# YouTube API Video Comments Count

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I am using following YouTube API to download Video Comments for provided VideoId (xxxxxxxx) in API call:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/xxxxxxxx/comments?v=2&max-results=50&start-index=1

I am not using any authentication to call above API and using it able to retrieve comments for that respective video. 
But, from yesterday when I call above API getting following error message:

```
403 Forbidden <errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>ServiceForbiddenException</code><internalReason>Commenting is disabled for this video.</internalReason></error></errors>
```

Please help me, what would be the reason behind this issue. Is this API deprecated? Is this API publicly available now (Means require authentication)? How can I sort out this issue any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide video ID of which you've tried to get comment? I believe the reason why you get the error is that commenting is disabled on the video as the error message you provided says.
For instance, you can still get comments of a video "KkRElOkQHlY".
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/KkRElOkQHlY/comments?v=2&max-results=50&start-index=1

With regard to comments, please confirm recent change on commenting system detailed in following document.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/changes_to_comments